# If $G$ is a group and $f: G \to G$ is defined by $f(x) = x^{-1}$ is it a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

I don't even know where to start here. Also, if it is a group homomorphism, I have to determine whether they are injective or surjective. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Do you know what $(xy)^{-1}$ is, for starters?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be.

Remember that when you define a group homomorphism, you have to specify the group structure on each set.

Let $(G,\star)$ be your group

Let $f:\begin{array}{l}(G,\star)\to (G,\star)\\x\mapsto x^{-1}\end{array}$

$f$ is a homomorphism $\iff$ $\begin{array}{l}f(e)=e\\
\forall x,y \in G, f(xy) = f(x)f(y)\\
\forall x \in G, f(x^{-1})=f(x)^{-1}\end{array}$

The first one and the third one are obiously true so

$f$ is a homomorphism $\iff \forall x,y \in G, y^{-1}x^{-1}=(xy)^{-1} = f(xy) = f(x)f(y)=x^{-1}y^{-1}$

$f$ is a homomorphism $\iff \forall x,y \in G, yx=xy$

$f$ is a homomorphism $\iff$ $(G,\star)$ is abelian

---

Now if you define $\forall x,y \in G, x \circ y = y \star x$

$f:\begin{array}{l}(G,\star)\to (G,\circ)\\x\mapsto x^{-1}\end{array}$

is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

By the very definition of a homomorphism, you need to start by checking if it is always true that

$$f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$$

Just rewrite that in terms of what the mapping $f$ actually does.